# Open, read, change and save an XML in node.js

Tags: xml, node.js, xml-documentation

I'm trying to open, read, change and save an xml in node.js
I'm using [XMLDoc](https://github.com/nfarina/xmldoc) but i'm stuck at the change and save phase.

Given this XML:

```
<widget version="1.0.0">
    <!-- NAME -->
    <name short="Name-en"></name>
</widget>
```

I want to open this `config.xml` file and set *foo* as content.

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/templates/widget_template/config.xml', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err)  return console.log(err);

    var document = new xmldoc.XmlDocument(data);
    document.descendantWithPath("name").value = 'foo';
    console.log(document.toString());
});
```

But when i do the `console.log(document.toString())` what I get is:

```
<widget version="1.0.0">
  <name short="Name-en"/>
</widget>
```

And what i'm trying to get is:

```
<widget version="1.0.0">
  <name short="Name-en">foo</name>
</widget>
```

Am I doing something wrong?, is there a better way to do this than using XMLDoc?, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm stupid, just changed

```
document.descendantWithPath("name").value = 'foo';
```

for

```
document.descendantWithPath("name").val = 'foo';
```

and it worked.